# What kind of surfaces are semi-vitreous?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I read a post somewhere recommending a certain way to remove some kind of residue, but the post said it would only work for (at least) **"semi-vitreous surfaces"**.

So, glass would fall under this category. But what else? What kind of surfaces/materials do people mean when they use this term?

A dictionary does [not](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/semi-vitreous) [help](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/vitreous) much.

Comment: "Vitreous" means "glass-like".  Presumably "semi-vitreous" means something *almost* as smooth, pore-free, and non-absorbent as glass.  It's a judgement call on your part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When specifying porcelain for tiles or work surfaces, one can have, in ascending order of porosity, **non-vitreous**, which holds the most water, **semi-vitreous** (in the middle), and **impervious**, which holds little or no water. In view of the stain-removal context, I would interpret "at least semi-vitreous" to mean "semi vitreous or impervious".

Comment: So, glass is impervious?

Comment: Have you checked the meaning of 'impervious' in a dictionary? Have you ever seen glass soak up water?

Comment: Yes and No, just wanted to make sure, because you would expect glass to be in a "vitreous" as opposed to "semi-vitreous" category.

Comment: _Of course_ glass is in a "vitreous category". That's what 'vitreous' means. Of all the things that can be glass-like, chief among them is.... glass!

Answer (score 0):

As you say Vitreous means glass. A fusion of Alumina amd Silica with a metallic Oxide which affects the temperature of the melting point and the colour.

Glazed tiles are fired at a temperature which fuses the body of the tile (mostly alumina) with silicates and white, clear or coloured oxides.

The same fusion produces a glassy surface on china and pottery.

Enameled jugs and bowls are also covered in aluminium-silicates (English spelling here).

So, Michael Harvey has given you the technical meaning, I hope this gives the in[image]formation to interpret the instructions.